# mat-select does not change placeholder value

Tags: angular, angular-material

Have mat-select, that should change placeholder if user choose one of radio button options

```html
<mat-select
  *ngIf="!data.loading"
  [placeholder]="form.get('dataType')?.value === 'test' ? 'Test-text' : 'Not-test'"
  formControlName="dataId"
>
```

For some reason, I see that placeholder changes in html code;
but this changes does not happened on page itself. Value
in mat-select field stays the same. It changes only if I click
on mat-select field.

Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder changes in html code [but not on the page]" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change the *value* of the select, and not the *placeholder*. The placeholder is only displayed before any value is selected. Use `[value]` to change the value. You can select from the values that you have assigned to `mat-option`s.

Example:

```html
<mat-select [value]="someVar ? 'v1' : 'v2'">
  <mat-option value="v1">Value 1</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="v2">Value 2</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

If you want to show the placeholder after a value has been selected, you will need to set the `value` to `undefined` or `null`. You can do that by two way binding `[(value)]` to a variable, and then assigning that variable in the component.

```html
<mat-select [(value)]="someVar" placeholder="hi">
  ...
</mat-select>
```

```js
showPlaceholder() {
  this.someVar = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

placeholder="{{form.get('dataType')?.value === 'test' ? 'Test-text' : 'Not-test'}}"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).